# Redirection not working on Aweber custom form on wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, forms, redirect, aweber

I use a custom Aweber form on my Wordpress blog squeeze page :

http://kuznitsazdoroviya.com/podarki/

Here is the code :

```
<form  method="post" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="******" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://kuznitsazdoroviya.com/" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="custom form" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_forward_vars" value="1" />
```

The registration is working fine but there is a problem with the redirection. I receive a 404 error because all the argument are add to the url.

So instead of going to the home page :  http://kuznitsazdoroviya.com

Here is the redirection url generated :

http://kuznitsazdoroviya.com/?email=bon****%40outlook.fr&from=bon****%40outlook.fr&listname=awlist*******&meta_adtracking=custom%20form&meta_message=1&meta_required=name%2Cemail&name=barbe&submit=Download%20free%20pdf

How can I tell aweber not to add this ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

So the anwser is simple, we only need to remove this line :

```
<input type="hidden" name="meta_forward_vars" value="1" />
```